# Authentication from localhost to rest api results CORS error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ionic-framework, cors, wordpress-rest-api

I just installed a fresh wp on a [dev server](http://dev.imok.ro/authworks). I am trying to authenticate to the rest api (plugin, since it's wp v.4.6.3), with an ionic/angularjs app which is located on my computer/device. Currently using [JWT Authentication for WP-API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) plugin. 
This is my header, with the help of HTTP Headers plugins:

```
content-encoding: gzip
x-powered-by: php/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 3361
keep-alive: timeout=5, max=95
access-control-allow-headers: accept, authorization, cache-control, cookie, content-type, origin
server: apache/2.4.7 (ubuntu)
x-frame-options: allow-from *
vary: accept-encoding
access-control-allow-methods: get, post, options, head, put, delete, trace, connect, patch
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-expose-headers: cache-control, cookie, content-type, origin
cache-control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
```

No matter what I do I get some CORS error. The most recent is:

> Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

The JWT plugin also had in docs some mention of editing .htaccess and wp-config.php, which I did. Tried several combinations of htacces edit and/or plugins. But same or similar error pops up.

This is my code, based on doc of JWT plugin (credentials/url valid!):

```
var apiHost = 'http://dev.imok.ro/authworks/wp-json';
$http.post( apiHost + '/jwt-auth/v1/token', {
   username: 'admin',
   password: 'admin!@#'
})
.then( function( response ) {
   console.log( 'siker', response.data )
})
.catch( function( error ) {
   console.error( 'Errorrrr', error );
});
```

.htaccess:

```
#<ifModule mod_headers.c>
#    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
##    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
##    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "content-type"
#</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

#SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /authworks/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /authworks/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks for your help!
Magor

Comment: Same issue for me

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this by editing public/class-jwt-auth-public.php to read

```
public function add_cors_support()
{
    $enable_cors = defined('JWT_AUTH_CORS_ENABLE') ? JWT_AUTH_CORS_ENABLE : false;
    if ($enable_cors) {
        remove_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', 'rest_send_cors_headers' );
        add_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', function( $value ) {
            header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' );
            header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, UPDATE, DELETE' );
            header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type' );
            header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
            return $value;
        });

        // $headers = apply_filters('jwt_auth_cors_allow_headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Content-Type, Authorization');
        // header(sprintf('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: %s', $headers));
    }
}
```

I have submitted a [PR](https://github.com/Tmeister/wp-api-jwt-auth/pull/65)

Comment: I AM NOT LUCK IT NOT WORK